# Google Apps Scripts self-starting at night

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

**Context:** I have a Google Spreadsheet with some data imported from the external API + some calculations done. API access + calculations are done using Google Apps Script. All those functions are within two files that belong to one project. Today in the morning I noticed multiple
`Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.` errors. Strange enough, as neither I nor the second collaborator was working overnight. When I checked executions, it turned out there were multiple executions over the night. It looked as if the document was refreshed every 20-30 minutes.

**Questions**

1. How can I check what triggered those functions?
2. Any ideas how to prevent those executions?

Comment: Did you set any triggers? Check all accounts that have access to see if there are any and update. If that doesn't work please post execution logs

Comment: No triggers at all.
The execution log prints only the error I posted above. 
The only clue I have is that maybe by sharing on Slack and granting access there (to make it possible to preview document) the document is refreshed that way.

Comment: If no triggers were set, you can check on the executions panel from Apps Script how many users have accessed the script. Did you check that?

Comment: Two people have access to this App Script. Me and my collaborator. Those executions come from outside our working hours. I wonder if having a spreadsheet open in a tab is enough to trigger a refresh.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? Does it keep doing the same?